# Letter Cyphering

Tags: ruby, loops, caesar-cipher

I am very lost on this, so any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to take sentences as inputs and return an output with all of the letters 3 places after the value given.  So "A" would turn into "D", "B" into "E" and so on.

I think would start out with values like:

```
Alphabet = ('a'..'z').split('')
function Cyphering
   precypheredLeters = inputSentence.split('')
   precypheredLeters.each do |x|
       if
```

After that bit of code I want to give "x" an index value (like if "x" is equal to the letter "C" the index value should be 3, then I can add 3 more onto that turning it into "F".

Also if my inputSentence is "Ruby Red !@#$", how do I return the value for spaces and symbols if I want them to remain the same?

And if a letter input is "Z", i'd want it to go from Z => 26 to C => 3, and "Y" would turn into "B".

Thanks!

Comment: `'abc xyz'.tr('a-z','d-z' + 'a-c' )  #=> "def abc"` or a less hard-coded way could be written as: `'abc xyz'.tr('a-z',('a'..'z').to_a.rotate(3).join ) #=> "def abc"`

Comment: `function Cyphering` – what programming language is that?

Comment: @Stefan also `('a'..'z').split('')` gives `NoMethodError (undefined method 'split' for "a".."z":Range)`.

Answer (score 1):

Stealing from Sagar's comment but this should work on your example string:

```
def lame_cipher(str)
  str.tr('a-zA-Z', 'd-za-cD-ZA-C')
end

lame_cipher 'Ruby Red !@#$'
#=> "Uxeb Uhg !@\#$"
```

or

```
def lame_cipher(str, int)
  cipher = [('a'..'z').to_a,('A'..'Z').to_a].map{|arr| arr.rotate(int) }.join
  str.tr('a-zA-Z', cipher)
end

lame_cipher('Ruby Red !@#$',3)
#=> "Uxeb Uhg !@\#$"

#This one can also decode:
lame_cipher("Uxeb Uhg !@\#$", -3)
#=> "Ruby Red !@\#$"
```

Comment: Maybe you could improve Sagar Pandya's code – a single `tr` call should be enough to replace both, uppercase and lowercase characters. And that `+` is not really needed.

Comment: I thought maybe in your second version you could have a second parameter to determine the rotation.

Comment: @Stefan I couldn't figure out how to get it to work with your suggestions, can you?

Comment: @lacostenycoder Try this: `str.tr('a-zA-Z', 'd-za-cD-ZA-C')`

Answer (score 1):

I like the `String#tr` solutions best, but here's another way to do it:

```
class Rot
  UPPER = ('A'.ord .. 'Z'.ord).freeze
  LOWER = ('a'.ord .. 'z'.ord).freeze

  attr_reader :n

  def initialize(n=13)
    @n = n
  end

  def cipher(str)
    str.unpack('U*').map do |o|
      if UPPER.cover?(o)
        UPPER.begin + (o - UPPER.begin + n) % UPPER.size
      elsif LOWER.cover?(o)
        LOWER.begin + (o - LOWER.begin + n) % LOWER.size
      else
        o
      end
    end.pack('U*')
  end
end

rot = Rot.new(3)
rot.cipher("Hello, world!") # => Khoor, zruog!
```

It works by breaking up and adjusting the codepoints selected by the two ranges defined as class constants.

---

Here's a refactored version of @lacostenycoder's `String#tr` solution:

```
class Lame
  UPPER = ('A' .. 'Z').to_a.freeze
  LOWER = ('a' .. 'z').to_a.freeze

  attr_reader :to

  def initialize(n=13)
    @to = [LOWER, UPPER].map { |a| a.rotate(n) }.join
  end

  def cipher(str)
    str.tr('a-zA-Z', to)
  end
end

require 'benchmark/ips'

lame = Lame.new
rot = Rot.new
str = 'sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow'.freeze

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('tr') { lame.cipher(str) }
  x.report('unpack') { rot.cipher(str) }
end
```

And benchmark results:

```
                  tr    475.305k (± 4.5%) i/s -      2.410M in   5.081979s
              unpack     64.604k (± 3.5%) i/s -    323.493k in   5.013385s
```

Comment: @lacostenycoder No, your `String#tr` solution is faster. I suspect your benchmark included the "startup time" of your solution—but not mine—in each iteration. I refactored your solution a bit and it's about 7.5X faster than mine.